# Cucumber with Capybara: How to unchoose a radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

Can I unchoose a radio button like you uncheck a checkbox?

I'm running a test where I'm going down different "branches" of a survey and I've come across this need. Thanks.

Comment: choose another radio button :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev LOL, you know what, that actually is a workable, common-sense solution. It would be cleaner if I could just clear that buttons, though

Comment: I'm not sure about capybara, but there's a JS solution, easy googlable.

Comment: Can you even do that in the browser?  I didn't think you could, in which case, why test it?

Comment: @Jon M if below is TL;DR -> I'm not testing the radio buttons, they're a dependency for what I am testing; else ->                                                                                                      I'm working on an app that dynamically generates subsequent questions depending upon the answers of previous questions. My main focus is to mimic set workflows and ensure the right questions show up. Since these workflows have different branches, I need to be able to clear out certain radio button choices as they change the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there doesn't appear to be an `unchoose` method in Capybara (which is curious given `select` & `check` both have corresponding "un" versions), given the [code for `choose`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/1.1.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L66), this should work:

```
def unchoose(locator)
  msg = "cannot choose field, no radio button with id, name, or label '#{locator}' found"
  find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.radio_button(locator), :message => msg).set(false)
end
```

Comment: Curious, implemented your code, the test didn't fail when it ran through the "unchoose" step, but the radio button still appeared to be selected

Answer (score 3):

Upon further investigation, this function was neither necessary nor advisable. @Jon M was right. If it can't be done by the users, why am including it in my testing.

FWIW my solution was to create a different scenario as part of the feature to test the separate branches, rendering this function unnecessary.

Props to Andrew for coming up with a solution anyways.

Comment: I was trying to work out, if you did achieve it, how the application under test would deal with an HTML radio button being unexpectedly un-selected!